# Primefaces <p:outputPanel/> or <div/>. what should I use for responsive?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, responsive-design, xhtml, responsive

With Primefaces what would be the best way for design good responsive pages? 
In Primefaces showcase I can see both tags, what is de difference between div and outputpanel? 
For a professional page what is the best choice? 
Maybe panelGrid?
I need a professional view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the PrimeFaces doc: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/performance

Try using HTML over JSF tags

1. Especially avoid using h:outputText if you don't need the escaping or other features like converters. Just use EL expressions inside your XHTML.
2. The same applies for some other components like p:outputPanel. Just use a plain div. If you need to make it updateable, you can still use "passthrough elements" `<div jsf:id="...">...</div>` or `jsf:rendered`. For example:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
    <div class="userDetails" jsf:rendered="#{sessionController.authorized}">
        Name: #{cc.attrs.value.name}
        Details: #{cc.attrs.value.details}
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In a lot of cases we need to use the tag rendered, so In this cases, should we use the jsf tag outputpanel?

Comment: you can still use jsf:rendered on a normal div. Looks bit nicer IMO ;)

Comment: But when I try to use it, I get the next wrong message:
"The prefix "jsf" for attribute "jsf:rendered" associated with an element type "div" is not bound."

Comment: Did you remember to include the jsf namespace `xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"` ?? What version of JSF are you using?

Comment: That's right, I was using a Primefaces template and with the tag all works fine. Thanks a lot!